# Conditional is not working as expected?

Tags: angular

I have this two components:

```
<app-z-grid [master]="true" title="Tip korisnika" *ngIf="showTab('Tip/podtip korisnika') || showTab('Tip korisnika')" [restPath]="'customertype'" (fillDetailParent)="reinit($event)"></app-z-grid>
     <app-z-grid title="Podtip korisnika" *ngIf="showTab('Tip/podtip korisnika') || showTab('Podtip korisnika')" [path]='"customerclassification/customerstype.json"' [restPath]="'customerstype'" [isDetail]="'customerstype'" [parentName]="'customertypeCode'" ></app-z-grid>
```

First one have master and second one not.

What i want is to set condtional to disabled buttons if its not master and if action.name !=='create':

```
[disabled]="(!master) && (action.name !== 'create')"
```

But problem is that is not working i get for first component all buttons enabled, and for second first is enabled. Any suggestion?

```
 <button *ngFor="let action of grid.actions" [disabled]="action.name !== 'create'" name="{{action.name}}"
                  type="submit" class="btn btn-block-container mousePointer" (click)="this[action.callback]('New', grid.actions)" title="{{action.label}}">
                  <i *ngIf="action.icon" style="color: white !important" class="{{action.icon}}"></i>
              </button>
```

json:

```
  "actions":[
          {"name":"create","label":"New", "icon":"fa fa-file buttonicon","disabled":false, "callback":"create"},
          {"name":"update","label":"Edit", "icon":"fa fa-pencil-square-o buttonicon", "disabled":true, "callback":"edit"},
          {"name":"deletemodal","label":"Delete", "icon":"fa fa-trash buttonicon", "disabled":true, "callback":"deletemodal"}
        ],
```

Comment: what is `master` and `action` refers ti

Comment: master is just that i know that is first component in template, and action where i have some functions ..create,edit,update , so i want to display only create

Comment: i added html for buttons how it looks like

Comment: I m little confused. share the json data.

Comment: What do you want to do? The problem is that a button is enabled on the second component? Or all are enabled on the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I correctly get it but, for you second component:

```
[disabled]="(!master) && (action.name !== 'create')"
```

We know that `master=false` then `!master=true`.
When we are on the button "create", `action.name =='create'` is true then `action.name !== 'create'` is false.

We have `true && false = false` so it's normal that your button is not disabled.

I don't know if it's what you want but if you only want to display the button create on master, you can put:

```
[disabled]="(!master) || ((!master) && (action.name !== 'create'))"
```

Comment: thats it... tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of bootstrap says if you want to disable a button you should use it as `disabled="disabled"` where as you are setting it as true or false..

Use a function to achieve this as

```
<button *ngFor="let action of data.actions" [disabled]="isDisabled(action)" name="{{action.name}}"
                  type="submit" class="btn btn-block-container mousePointer" (click)="this[action.callback]('New', grid.actions)" title="{{action.label}}">
      <i *ngIf="action.icon" style="color: white !important" class="{{action.icon}}"></i>
       </button>
```

Code

```
isDisabled(action):boolean{
    if(action.name !== 'create'){
      return 'disabled'
  }
  else return ''
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/t1WTsIuYukaqfOA9IRZg?p=preview)**

Comment: it will disable all three buttons. did you try it?

Comment: I'm talking in general, I put boolean in my [disabled] attributes and it works. You don't need functions

Comment: when you are using `[disabled]` as property binding it will not work,